# Add link to GLTF object in aframe

Tags: aframe, gltf

Is it possible to add a link to an GLTF 3d object (which is triggered with a marker?)

I've tried the usual 'a-link' method, the onClick method, even applying an id and using jQuery - all without luck - any help would be appreciated.

```
<a-scene embedded arjs>
  <a-marker id="dragon" preset="custom" type="pattern" url="pattern-dragonfly.patt">
    <a-entity animation-mixer="clip: *;" scale="1.5 1.5 1.5" gltf-model-next="src: url(dragon.gltf);"></a-entity>
  </a-marker>

  <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: What is `gltf-model-next`? Why not using the [built-in component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/gltf-model.html#sidebar)?

Comment: It is of course possible to turn a gltf model into a link. It involves adding a raycaster system, and creating a custom component that traverses the gltf model to look for matches with what the raycaster returns, and then calling function that executes the link, which presumably opens a new web browser tab. Perhaps it makes sense for you to describe precisely what you want to happen.

Comment: @Diego gltf-model-next works without the need for a separate a-assets

Comment: @Thomas, thanks - basically, when the user touches the 3D object I want them to be taken to a website - is there a working example of what you have suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, you need to create a cursor with a raycaster, and a custom component for the gltf.

```
 <a-entity id="mouseCursor" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .clickable"></a-entity>
 <a-entity id="tree" gltf-model="#gltftree" scale="5 5 5" treeman class="clickable"  ></a-entity>
```

Inside the custom component, first you traverse the gltf and store references to the models that you want to be interactive, like this

```
 init: function(){
                let el = this.el;
                let self = this;
                self.trees = [];              
                el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e =>{
                    let tree3D = el.getObject3D('mesh');
                    if (!tree3D){return;}    
                  console.log('tree3D', tree3D);
                    tree3D.traverse(function(node){
                        if (node.isMesh){   
                          console.log(node);
                          self.trees.push(node);                          
                          node.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x33aa00});
                        }
                    });
              });
```

Then you make event listeners that detect intersection events, and save which object has been intersected, and highlight it, so users know it is live, like this

```
el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', e =>{  
                self.raycaster = e.detail.el;
                let intersection = self.raycaster.components.raycaster.getIntersection(el);
                  console.log('click', intersection.object.name, self.mouseOverObject, 
                            intersection.object.name != self.mouseOverObject );  
                if (self.mouseOverObject != intersection.object.name){
                  intersection.object.material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0xFFFF00);
                  intersection.object.material.emissiveIntensity = 0.5; 
                } else {
                   intersection.object.material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
                  intersection.object.material.emissiveIntensity = 0.0; 
                }                  
                  self.mouseOverObject = intersection.object.name;
              });

               el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected-cleared', e =>{  
                self.trees.forEach(function(tree){
                   tree.material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
                  tree.material.emissiveIntensity = 0.0; 
                });    
                  self.mouseOverObject = null;
              });
```

Finally add a click listener that operate the hyperlink, like this

```
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log(self.mouseOverObject);
                if(self.mouseOverObject === "Trunk_A"){
                  console.log('link');
                  let url = 'https://supermedium.com/supercraft/';
                  let win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                  win.focus();
                }
              });
```

[glitch here](https://glitch.com/~gltf-link)

Click the trunk to activate the hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks! (apologies for the delayed reply)